# How to keyword search only tweets from 'People you Follow' in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is it possible to use the API search in Tweepy to restrict a keyword search to only people you follow? For example, on the web, the URL would be: https://twitter.com/search?q=keyword&f=live&pf=on

I tried using the pf= paramater, since that is what shows up in the web URL. For example: pf='on' or pf=true. But it is still returning unfiltered tweets.

What I have currently:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q='keyword',
                           result_type='recent',
                           pf='on').items(20)
```

I don't see any reference to this in the API docs. Is there some other it would have to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing available in the search API that would let you do this using an operator directly. One (clunky) way you could achieve this would be to put all the the people you are following onto a Twitter list, and then use the `list:username/listname` operator inside the `q` parameter to limit the search to the accounts in that list.